# Can you target a specific port using icmp?

Tags: go, tcp, ip, icmp

I believe the title is pretty self explanatory, but just in case, I'll explain further.

I am writing a function in Go that uses icmp to check if a particular service is running.  I got this idea from ping implemented in Go.  When I try command line ping, it can not resolve `127.0.0.1:8080`, and the function follows suit, which makes sense.  But can I use icmp to check that address and port with something I missing? Or should I just stick something like tcp to target a port?

Right now I have this simple function, and I *could* just use tcp, but I'm curious if I could use something like icmp.

```
func (c *Controller) Ping() error {
    conn, connErr := net.Dial("ip4:icmp", c.APIServerIP)
    if connErr != nil {
        return connErr
    }
    conn.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(3 * time.Second))
    defer conn.Close()
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No. There are no ports in ICMP.

If you want to know whether a specific TCP server is running, try to connect to it.